# Error stating same jobid in systemuid - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, debugging, operating-system, jobs

When starting application the app closes and logs this error. How can I stop this from happening. The app no longer works due to this error. Your help is much appreciated. Many Thanks.

```
2019-05-26 21:34:09.147 932-4145/? E/JobScheduler: jobid:20536
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Same jobid in systemuid.
        at com.android.server.job.JobSchedulerService.scheduleAsPackage(JobSchedulerService.java:889)
        at com.android.server.job.JobSchedulerService$JobSchedulerStub.schedule(JobSchedulerService.java:2601)
        at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule(JobSchedulerImpl.java:44)
        at com.android.server.backup.FullBackupJob.schedule(FullBackupJob.java:54)
        at com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService$3.run(BackupManagerService.java:1925)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Comment: Can you change the value of your Job Id?

Comment: I am unaware of how to do so and how to sort this issue. If you could help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you not schedule any Jobs yourself? Maybe you have two libraries that schedule jobs with the same id values (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414771/jobscheduler-how-do-i-determine-a-unique-job-id)

Comment: Ah it is probably a clash in dependency job id. Is there any way I can find which is the issue.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry. If this problem was only introduced into your app recently and you can recreate the crash, you can start removing dependencies one-by-one until you find the one that's causing your crash. From there you'll just have to see whether there's any way you can modify the job id yourself - if it isn't part of the existing API you can request it from the library's maintainer or, if it's open source, fork it and add the functionality yourself.

Comment: Basically only thing ive done is update dependencies. So if I update JOBID may change ??.

Comment: Issue is if I remove dependency I have to go through all app classes and remove modules. Which seems very inefficient unless there is a way around this.